# Trying in app subscription but showing error "D/GoogleBillingService: buy. Google billing service is not ready yet."

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play-console

I am trying to add an in-app subscription to my app but it is showing this error in the log **"D/GoogleBillingService: buy. Google billing service is not ready yet."**

I've added the license from the play store to the app & using "Use Google Play Billing only". Created Subscriptions & added the product id to the app. Idk where I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instruction from Google itself. It should work with no problems. Check, which steps you missed. The instruction is available here: [Integrate the Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate)

Do not forget to create In-app products in Monetize section in Google Play console details for your app.